# Color PieChart Export in Excel

Tags: java, excel, colors, export

I need to export a PieChart in Excel. The export is working so far but some of the colors of the chart are the same. 
Can't figure out the Problem.

Here's the code:

```
Color[] c = this.createRainbow(100);
int n = chart.getDataPointCount(0); //number of Pies
ArrayList<Integer> compare = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int j = 0; j < n && !ValueWatcherServer.canceled_id.contains(connectionid); j++) {
    int rePos = (int)(((double)j / (double)n * (double)c.length));                    
    ChartFormat format = chart.getDataPointFormat(0, j);
    format.setSolid();
        if(!compare.contains(rePos)){
            compare.add(rePos);
            format.setForeColor(c[rePos].getRGB());
        }
        else{
            format.setForeColor(3);
        }
     chart.setDataPointFormat(0, j, format);
 }
```

the result is this:
[image: pie chart]